# BigQuery: Expensive full table scans when there's nothing to JOIN to

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have two tables, Table A is 500gb+ table of information on people (clustered on id). Table B is a narrow lookup table of just the IDs from Table A and public URL column (Facebook, Linkedin, etc) (clustered on publicURL, and tblA_id). These URLs are in Table A, but in a array inside a record so I can't cluster on it.

I thought I could use Table B for searching Table A with just a join and "Where URL in (URL1, URL2, URL3, URL4)". This initially worked great. It cut queries from hundreds of gb to a few 100mb.

Problem: It's not guaranteed the queried URL will be in the tables. If at least one of the URLs is found it's a normal expense of 100mb more or less, but if a query is performed with an unknown URL or NULL inside those parentheses an entire table scan is executed and costs 500gb.

I've written this query a few ways, and the problem exists regardless. What I've tried:

```
SELECT
    A.*
FROM TableB AS B
JOIN TableA AS A
    ON A.id = B.tblA_id
 WHERE B.public_url IN (
     "linkedin.com/in/bingcrosby",
     "linkedin.com/in/hillaryclinton",
     "facebook.com/billhicks"
 );
```

Other option that has the same problem:

```
SELECT
    A.*
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT tblA_id
    FROM TableB
    WHERE public_url IN (
        "linkedin.com/in/bingcrosby",
        "linkedin.com/in/hillaryclinton",
        "facebook.com/billhicks"
    )
);
```

Both work cheaply and efficiently as long as at least one public URL is found. How can I prevent a whole table scan if some unknown URL in Table B is used? I'd be happy even if I could generate an error from the subquery, anything.

Thanks for your advice. This is starting to get expensive.

Comment: One option would be partitioning on URL or by a portion of the URL.

Comment: Interesting idea, like ABS(MOD(FARM_FINGERPRINT(B.public_url), number_of_partitions))? This should limit the table scan. Though, we'd have to apply it across the input array of URLs, meaning dynamic SQL, no? I've always found that bad for readability and maintenance. I guess I could minimize that with a WITH quasi-temp table.

Comment: . . Yes, you would need to apply the same function to the inputs for comparison.  And if you use hashing (as in your example) you would need to still do the actual comparisons just in case there is a collision.

Comment: Welp, tried this. Same problem. It keeps wanting to join to all of Table A on nothing. Which just seems like a bug at this point.

```
SELECT
    A.full_name
FROM TableB AS B
JOIN TableA AS A
    ON A.id = B.TblA_id
    AND B.url_partition IN (
     ABS(MOD(FARM_FINGERPRINT("facebook.com/billhicks"),4000))
 )
 WHERE B.public_url IN (
     "facebook.com/billhicks"
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution that I don't love, but works. I ended up having to make a stored procedure, make a temp table of Table B, check if the length is greater than 0, and then join that to Table A.

In BigQuery, the results of a SProc aren't returned so the "Query results" tab directly so that's a mild annoyance (you can see the results in the "Job History" tab -> "View Results" button).

I'm not sure BigQuery stored procedures benefit from the advantages of traditional SQL databases like execution caching, or pre-parsing. At BigQuery scale I don't expect it matters much.

You do get the intrinsic advantages like security, SQL injection prevention, and maintenance remaining with data team. So this convoluted solution to a seeming simple problem comes with benefits.

I think it's ridiculous the query optimizer doesn't go "Oh, there's nothing to join to on an inner join? Better stop then." Anywho, here's my solution for the interested.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `<project-id>.dataset.profile_url_search`(urls ARRAY<STRING>)
BEGIN

    CREATE TEMP TABLE ids_found_for_urls(tblA_id STRING)
    AS
    SELECT tblA_id
    FROM `<project-id>.dataset.TableB`
        WHERE public_url IN UNNEST(urls);

    IF (SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) > 0 AS BOOL) FROM ids_found_for_urls)
    THEN
        SELECT
            A.*
        FROM `<project-id>.dataset.TableA` AS A
        JOIN ids_found_for_urls
            ON A.id = ids_found_for_urls.tblA_id;
    ELSE 
        SELECT NULL;
    END IF;
END
```

This is then invoked by:

```
CALL `<project-id>.dataset.profile_url_search` (ARRAY<STRING>[
    "linkedin.com/in/bingcrosby",
    "linkedin.com/in/hillaryclinton",
    "facebook.com/billhicks"
])
```

If anyone has performance or design suggestions, I humbly welcome them.